# return 0 after joining two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

im trying to display all the items sold and not sold within a period of time

im unable to display on the join tables all the items that have previously arrived if there were none sold.

```
select arrivals.description,
    COALESCE(sum(orders.quantity ), 0) as quantity
    from arrivals
    left join
    orders
    on  arrivals.description = orders.description
    where orders.date between '2022-11-01' and '2022-12-20'
    group by orders.description`ARRIVALS
```

the problem is that by referencig orders.date doesnt display descriptions where nothing was sold within that period, it works if i use arrivals.date but i want to display the dates from orders.

```
ORDERS
```

| id | date | description | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2022-11-27 | nike 500 black 70 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-11-24 | nike 500 black 70 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-11-24 | nike 500 black 60 | 1 |
| 6 | 2022-11-28 | adidas 1000 white 90 | 1 |
| 5 | 2022-11-27 | adidas 1000 white 90 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-10-31 | adidas 1000 white 90 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-10-31 | adidas 1000 white 80 | 1 |

```
--------------------------------------------------------
ARRIVALS
```

| id | date | description | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-30 | nike 500 black 50 | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-10-30 | nike 500 black 60 | 3 |
| 3 | 2022-10-30 | nike 500 black 70 | 4 |
| 4 | 2022-10-29 | adidas 1000 white 80 | 2 |
| 5 | 2022-10-29 | adidas 1000 white 90 | 3 |
| 6 | 2022-10-29 | adidas 1000 white 110 | 2 |

---

i only get this result:

| description | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| nike 500 black 60 | 1 |
| nike 500 black 70 | 2 |
| adidas 1000 white 90 | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the condition on order date from the `where` clause to the join condition:

```sql
select
    a.description,
    sum(coalesce(o.quantity, 0)) as quantity
from arrivals a
left join orders o on a.description = o.description
    and o.date between '2022-11-01' and '2022-12-20'
group by 1
```

The reason this works is that when you put a condition on an outer joined table in the where clause you effectively change the join from an *outer* join to an *inner* join.

Other cosmetic changes were made to the query to improve readability such as standard formatting, use of aliases, etc.

Comment: didnt know i could use between dates without where.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to `orders.date between '2022-11-01' and '2022-12-20'` is in the `where` clause. If you want to include everything in `arrivals` and only `orders` with `orders.date between '2022-11-01' and '2022-12-20'`, you can move it to `select` as below:

```sql
select a.description,
       sum(if(o.date between '2022-11-01' and '2022-12-20', o.quantity, 0)) as quantity
  from arrivals a
  left
  join orders o
    on a.description = o.description
 group by a.description;
```

Result:

```
description          |quantity|
---------------------+--------+
nike 500 black 50    |       0|
nike 500 black 60    |       1|
nike 500 black 70    |       2|
adidas 1000 white 80 |       0|
adidas 1000 white 90 |       2|
adidas 1000 white 110|       0|
```

Comment: thanks I cant take advantage of this approach as i can display sells within 15, 30 , 45 days

Comment: select
 a.description,
       
sum(if(o.date between '2022-11-01' and '2022-11-16', o.quantity, 0)) as '15 days',
sum(if(o.date between '2022-11-01' and '2022-12-01', o.quantity, 0)) as '30 days',
sum(if(o.date between '2022-11-01' and '2022-12-01', o.quantity, 0)) as '45 days'

  from arrivals a
  left
  join orders o
    on a.description = o.description
group by a.description